# @controller is nil error on minitest at particular case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have added the following code in the test helper. I am using minitest.

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

def default_url_options
  Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
end
```

When I ran the controller test I am getting the below errors.
@controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method is coming

However, the service is working fine. I could not find the correct reason for that. Does anyone know that?

I need the above in service and I can not change the entire controller tests to support,

```
def setup
  @controller = Controller.new 
end
```

Comment: Your `setup` method is not executed before the test.

Answer (score 0):

Have use check the `assigns` variable in your minitest.

It consists of all the instance variables defined in controller in form of key-value pair

So check for `assigns[:controller]`